# unity text trigger not working as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in my game im trying to make text appear on the ui when entering a specific room,but when i try to go into that room nothing happens

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Room_trigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject UiObject;
    public GameObject cube;

    void Start()
    {
        UiObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {

        if (other.tag == "player")
        {
            UiObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {

    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        UiObject.SetActive(false);
        Destroy(cube);
    }
}
```

the player controller is based of of brakeys fps controller tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things you will need to check:

1. Does the player object (the one that the player capsule collider component is attached to) have the tag "player" assigned to it?  Is it definitely "player" and not "Player" or "Player1".  Note - the TAG of an object is not the same as the NAME of an object.
2. Is the "Is Trigger" on the capsule collider on the player object ticked/checked?  If the player capsule collider is not a trigger then it won't cause OnTriggerEnter to be fired by your Room_trigger attached object.  Also check the next point.
3. If you don't want your player capsule collider to be a trigger (which is highly likely), then make sure that the object your Room_trigger script is attached to has:

   - a collider that is set to Is Trigger
   - a Rigidbody component

A couple of other possibilities are that you haven't dragged GameObjects into the UiObject and/or cube fields in the Unity Editor UI but that should throw NullReference errors in the console when you run the game.

Whilst Vasmos is correct, you should compare strings using the Equals() method, that's not going to be the cause of your trouble in this specific case.  Comparing strings using == as you've done here will work.

Comment: yea, after watching a different tutorial he sayed to not forget to set the cube as trigger, thanks for detailed response (video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNNeD9oT4DY)

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
   if (other.tag == "player")
```

with

```
   if (other.tag.Equals("player"))
```

always use .Equals for comparing strings, otherwise its just comparing if its the same variable

Comment: does the name in the quote have to match the player id in the object list? (ei; the player is refered to as fps player in unity, does is have to be the same in teh C# spript?

Comment: @PatrickCoots It doesn't have to match the name of the object in the object list.  It needs to match the TAG of the object.  To see what tag an object has, click on the object in the hierarchy and then look at the tag drop down that is below the object's name in the inspector panel on the right hand side of your screen.

Answer (score 0):

@HumanWrites i figured out what the problem was, the cube wasn't set as trigger, the i watched a different tutorial and he sayed "dont forget to set the collider as trigger" and that fixed it.